# Service routine vs Interrupt service routine?

Tags: lc3

I've been reviewing some slides for the computer science class I am in and I've seen the word service routine thrown around a lot. Now I know what an interrupt service routine is but I can't really seem to find a set definition on what a service routine in general is.

Is there any difference between a service routine or an ISR is what I'm aiming to find out?

Comment: What's the context in which 'service routine' is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of service routines in the LC-3

Trap Service Routines and Interrupt Service Routines.

A Trap Service Routine would be the code that gets executed as part of a trap.  The Trap vector table which contains the addresses of the trap service routines is located from x00 - xFF.  So if you wanted to see the code for the HALT trap look in memory address x25 and then that will tell you the address of the code that handles the HALT trap.

An Interrupt Service Routine is just code to handle an interrupt.  The LC-3 has only two things that can cause interrupts, the console and an exception.  The interrupt vector table is located from x100 - x1FF and like the TVT contains the addresses of the code to handle them.  For the console that would be x180, and for the two types of exceptions x100 and x101 (privelege mode exception, and illegal opcode respectively).

Comment: Thanks alot that definitely helps!